# How would I form an equation to solve this question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-12<2x+1<-7$$
Find all solutions for x

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe i have found the answer using hirshy's comment. Split them as −12<2x+1,2x+1<−7 and then put them together as -13/2<x<-4

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you don't want to deal with this double inequation, first solve $$-12<2x+1,\quad 2x+1<-7$$ individually. Then you can put it all together.

Comment: would i go x>-13/2, x<-4 and then put them together as -13/2<x<-4

Comment: Looks good! And for the future: you can apply the same manipulations to solve for $x$ to the double inequation: $$-12<2x+1<-7 \Leftrightarrow -13<2x<-8 \Leftrightarrow -\frac{13}{2}<x<-4.$$

Comment: I see, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

We start from $$-12<2x+1<-7$$ Adding $(-1)$ to all sides gives us $$\Rightarrow -12 + (-1)<2x +1 +(-1)<-7+(-1)$$ $$\Rightarrow -13 <2x<-8$$ Dividing by $2$ gives us $$\Rightarrow -\frac{13}{2} <\frac{2x}{x}<-\frac{8}{2}$$ $$\Rightarrow -\frac{13}{2} <x<-4$$ $$\Rightarrow x \in (-\frac{13}{2},-4)$$

Comment: thankyou, this method is great

Comment: @Okeh You're welcome. You can also upvote and accept my answer if you like it. ;)